# Transition not working on checkbox when unchecking

Tags: css

I have tried multiple methods to get this transition to work, however, ran out of ideas. The transition works fine when checking, but not unchecking. Things I have tried:

- not using visibility to unhide `more-info` div
- using all, however, it transitions, but with a fade affect, which is not what I want `transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;`

HTML:

```
<input :id="id" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" role="button">
<div class="more-info">
Content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .more-info {
      max-height: 0;
      transition: max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: calc(100% + 2px);
      margin-bottom: -1px;
    }

    .checkbox {
      display: none;
    }

    .checkbox:checked ~ .more-info {
      max-height: 700px;
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

Comment: Providing a running example is usually helpful

Answer (score 0):

`visibility: hidden;` and `opacity: 0;` cancels the animation, as, in theory, the animation is running in `max-height`, the fact that you set it as `hidden` doesn't show the expected result.

Removing `visibility: hidden;` and adding `opacity` to your transition should fix the problem, `opacity` will hide the element while `max-height` goes to 0